# Create a copy of the list not referencing the contained objects

Tags: python, object

Say I have a vector `a` defined as:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]]
```

I have learned that to create a copy of the object `a` without referencing it I should use the following syntaxis:

```
b = a[:]
```

Indeed, if I execute the following statements:

```
b = []
print a
```

the output is

```
>>> [[1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]]
```

exactly as I was expecting. Though, if I do the following:

```
b = a[:]
b[0][2] = 'change a'
print a
```

the output is

```
>>> [[1,2,'change a'],[-1,-2,-3]]
```

So it's clear to me that the object `a[0]` is being referenced even if contained in `a`. How can I create a copy of the object `a` in a way that even all its internal objects will not be referenced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that use `deepcopy`:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> b = deepcopy(a)

>>> b[0][2] = 'change a'
>>> print a
[[1,2,3],[-1,-2,-3]]
```

Deepcopy: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

#### Extension

Deepcopy also creates an individual copy of class instances. Please see simple example below.

```
from copy import deepcopy

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 'A'

>>> a = A()
>>> b = deepcopy(a)

>>> b.val = 'B'
>>> print a.val
'A'
>>> print b.val
'B'
```

Answer (score 5):

`a[:]` creates a *shallow* copy of the list.

You can use the [`copy.deepcopy()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to recursively copy the objects, or use a list comprehension:

```
b = [el[:] for el in a]
```

This creates a new list object with shallow copies of the nested list objects in `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Quoting the docs:

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original

Example:

```
>>> a = list(range(1000))
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a is b    # b is a new object
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only "shallow copy" `b = a[:]`, each sub-list `b[n]` is still a reference to the same sub-list referenced at `a[n]`. Instead you need to do a deep(er) copy, e.g. by

```
b = [l[:] for l in a]
```

This creates a shallow copy of each sub-list, but as their contents are immutable that isn't a problem. If you have more levels of container nesting, you need `copy.deepcopy` as the other answers suggest.